# Schematics for no longer valid property fails for some users but not for others

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, angular-schematics

We have four different devs on the project.
The angular.json file for all the libs have the below lines:

```
"schematics": {
        "@nrwl/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      }
```

It is like this for ages now. About two weeks ago we updated the project from angular 10 to 11. Everything worked fine. But now, 2 out of 4 developers receive the below error when running `ng g c component-name`:

```
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"style":"scss","changeDetection":"OnPush","styleext":"scss","path":"libs/section/ehm-watchlist-report/src/lib/ehm-watchlist-report/views","name":"test","project":"section-ehm-watchlist-report"}
Errors:

  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(styleext).
```

If I update the schematics line on angular.json from `styleext` to `style` the error goes away from the devs with the problem, but that does not explain why I have some devs with the problem and others not.

Angular cli version is the same for all devs. Node versions are 14.15.1 (error), 14.16.1 (no error) 14.17.1 (error).

Any ideas of what could be causing the problem?

Comment: Are you facing issue with angular 12?

Comment: We are running angular 11 at the moment. Migrated from 10 (about 2 months ago).